# Rails OpenID Authentication Plugin No Longer Installs Rake Tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid, authlogic

I'm following the Railscasts tutorial on [using OpenID with AuthLogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/170-openid-with-authlogic).

This command:

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication.git
```

installs the plugin, but I don't see any OpenID Rake tasks (rake -T). In particular, I can no longer run the task:

```
$ rake open_id_authentication:db:create
```

With previous applications, the Rake tasks were installed without a problem, so what's changed with the plugin? Which version of the plugin do I need to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Using Rails 2.3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the task has been taken out (unnecessary?). [This bug report](http://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication/issues/unreads#issue/3) (link now broken but less than one hour ago worked) outlines the problem, but doesn't seem to give a definite answer of what's going on.