# OpenID Authentication using AuthLogic Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am trying to implement openid authentication using authlogic. I have installed the open_id_authentication in the process but when I entered

```
rake open_id_authentication:db:create --trace
I get the following error

(in /Users/felix/login)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'open_id_authentication:db:create'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1728:in `[]'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2050:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Can someone tell what am i doing incorrectly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin has been broken for some time. Some reports indicate it can be made to work by using older copies of an underlying plugin found on Github. I played around with it an never could find a combination of plugins/gems to make it work.

[Duplicate Posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596795/rails-openid-authentication-plugin-no-longer-installs-rake-tasks)